# Smartcontractにて同じファイルに2つのクラスを持つSolidityをpy-solc-xでコンパイルするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Tags: ethereum, solidity

今まではRemixかTruffleを使って、SmartcontractのDeployを実行していました。
PythonでDeploy出来ればいいなと思い、py-solc-xを使うことにしました。
そこで起きた問題が解決出来ずに、今回お力を貸していただきたいです。

pythonから抜粋

```
 compile_source(source, output_values=["abi", "bin"], solc_version=_solc_version)

中略

    tx = contract.constructor("Hi!").build_transaction(
        dict(
            chainId=web3_connect.connect_provider["chain_id"],
            nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount(FROM_ADDRESS),
            type=2,
            gas=1000000,
            maxFeePerGas=web3_connect.gwei_to_wei(math.ceil(gas_station["maxFee"])),
            maxPriorityFeePerGas=web3_connect.gwei_to_wei(math.ceil(gas_station["maxPriorityFee"])),
        )
    )
```

solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {
    string public msg;

    constructor(string memory message) {
        msg = message;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

上記のケースでは正常にdeployすることが出来ました。

solidityに新たなVersionクラスを追加し継承させました。

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Version {
    string private _version;

    constructor(string memory version_) {
        _version = version_;
    }

    function version() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _version;
    }
}

contract Test is Version {
    string public msg;

    constructor(string memory message, string memory version) Version(version) {
        msg = message;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return msg;
    }
}
```

constructorの引数が増えているので、pythonを以下のように変更しました。

```
    tx = contract.constructor("Hi!", "1.0.0").build_transaction(
        dict(
            chainId=web3_connect.connect_provider["chain_id"],
            nonce=w3.eth.getTransactionCount(FROM_ADDRESS),
            type=2,
            gas=1000000,
            maxFeePerGas=web3_connect.gwei_to_wei(math.ceil(gas_station["maxFee"])),
            maxPriorityFeePerGas=web3_connect.gwei_to_wei(math.ceil(gas_station["maxPriorityFee"])),
        )
    )
```

このpythonを実行するとエラーになりました。

```
 "Incorrect argument count.  Expected '1'.  Got '2'"
```

abiを取得すると、Versionクラスの分のみとなっているため、引数の数が一致しないということまではわかりました。

remixだとどのクラスをコンパイルするか指定できますが、py-solc-xでも同じように出来ないでしょうか？
もしくはVersionクラスの書き方が良くないのか、どなたかご存じないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

載せていないコードに問題というか考慮不足がありました。

```
    compiled_sol = compile_source_file(SOLC_VERSION, main_contract + ".sol")
    contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()
    abi = contract_interface["abi"]
```

というようにして、abiを取得していました。
`compile_source_file`関数は独自で、内部では`py-solc-x.compile_source()`を実行しています。

複数のクラスがある場合、`len(compiled_sol)`で参照すると今回の場合、`2`となります。
その結果、popitemでは最初の一つ目を取ってくることとなり、Versionクラスのabiを返しBaseクラスの取得が漏れてしまいました。

```
    main_contract = "Base"
    while True:
        contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()
        if main_contract in contract_id:
            break
        if len(compiled_sol) <= 0:
            result = {
                "error": "Compile Failed",
            }
            pprint.pprint(result)
            return result
```

上記のようにループしてチェックするようにしました。